# Display data from a drop down in the view asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a view that needs to display a drop-down and then displaying data from the drop-down in the same view using viewBag

There is 3 tables customer, assign, employee. Assign and employee have a relationship but the customer does not and is not needed so ViewBag is being used to display data in another view, how I build a drop-down list displayed in the view using the viewBag and display the selected data from the customer table in the same view?

The view  that the data is needed to be displayed in mainly the name, task, and image from the URL

```
@model HandyApp.Models.ViewModels.AsignVM

<div>
// drop down needed in this section
</div>
<div>
//  display data from selected drop down item needed in this section
</div>

<form method="post" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Customer task</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><strong style="margin-right: 7px;">Name :</strong><span style="margin-top: 1px;">harry</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><strong>Tasks :</strong><span style="margin-left: 12px;">paint shed</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><strong>Telephone number :</strong><span style="margin-left: 12px;">000000000000</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col"><strong>Address :&nbsp;</strong><span>123 Fake Street</span><span></span></div>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 31px;">
                <h3 style="margin-left: 0px;">Assign tasks</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label style="margin-left: 47px;">Name of customer</label>
                <input asp-for="Asign.Name" class="form-control" type="text" value="customers name" style="margin-top: 2px;">
                <label style="margin-top: 8px;">Employee Assign&nbsp;</label>
                <select asp-for="Asign.EmployeeNameId" asp-items="@Model.TypeDropDown" class="form-control">
                    <option selected>-- Select option</option>
                </select>
                <label style="margin-top: 8px;">Employee Assign&nbsp;</label>
                <select asp-for="Asign.Status" class="form-control">
                    <option value="in progress" selected="">in progress</option>
                    <option value="completed">completed</option>
                </select>
            </div>
          
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label style="margin-left: 54px;">Tasks&nbsp;</label>
                    <input asp-for="Asign.Tasks" class="form-control" value="Enter tasks here" style="margin-top: 4px;">
                
                    <label style="margin-top: 8px;">Telephone</label>
                    <input asp-for="Asign.Telephone" value="Type telephone" class="form-control" type="text">
                    <label tyle="margin-top: 8px;">Address</label>
                    <input asp-for="Asign.Address" class="form-control" value="enter address" type="text"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="margin-top: 35px;margin-left: 34px;">Submit</button>
        </div>
    
</form>
```

Customer model

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tasks { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Assign model

```
public class Assign
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tasks { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeNameId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EmployeeNameId")]
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Employee model

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Speciality { get; set; }
}
```

Assign ViewModel

```
public class AssignVM
{
    public Assign Assign { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TypeDropDown { get; set; }
}
```

Assign controller

```
public class AssignController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public AssignController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Asign> objList = _db.Assigns;
        IEnumerable<Customer> custObj = _db.Customers;

        foreach (var obj in objList)
        {
            obj.Employee = _db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == obj.EmployeeNameId);
        }

        ViewBag.Customer = custObj;

        return View(objList);
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        AssignVM assignVM = new AssignVM()
        {
            Assign = new Assign(),
            TypeDropDown = _db.Employees.Select(i => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = i.Name,
                Value = i.Id.ToString()
            })
        };

        return View(assignVM);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(AssignVM obj)
    {
        _db.Assigns.Add(obj.Assign);

        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || id == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var obj = _db.Assigns.Find(id);

        if (obj == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(obj);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult DeletePost(int? id)
    {
        var obj = _db.Assigns.Find(id);

        if (obj == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _db.Assigns.Remove(obj);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the maximum expected amount of customers?

Comment: 20, Due to there being an image I don't want it to fill the screen with them all, just the selected  customer  to show their data rather than displaying all the customers in one list

Comment: You have multiple options. One of them: When user selects a customer, use javascript to update the url to "/xx/customers/SELECTED-CUSTOMER-ID". This will reload the page. Now you can read the id in your controller action and you can show the correct customer in your view.

Comment: is there a way to not use javascript and use asp.net only?

Comment: You could simply submit the form? (But I'd recommend JavaScript in this case - sounds to me simpler and cleaner)

Comment: true javascript would be cleaner, would another viable option be to create a small customer API , so that when the item is selected it will make a javascript call to the api and load the data? saves the page reloading as it is only needed to display data not post etc

Comment: Using javascript to load the data is very common. You can do this for one page only or you could move to an SPA where you fully separate the the client (a JavaScript app) from the server (ASP core, but without views, just JSON). For "just one page" pure JS or jQuery are common options, for SPAs Angular, React and Vue are common frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a jquery to get data from controller will be the easiest way, you can check my demo:

The image is stored in wwwroot/Images/*** in my demo.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetCustomer(string Id)
    {
        var img = _db.Customers.Where(x => x.Id.ToString()==Id).ToList();
        return Json(img);
    }
```

View:

```
<div>
    <select class="form-control" id="select1" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.customers,"Value", "Text"))">
    </select>
</div>
<div id="showhere">  
</div>
//........your other html

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#select1").change(function () {
            var Id = $("#select1 option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Get',
                url: 'Assign/GetCustomer',
                data: { Id: Id },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    document.getElementById("showhere").innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById("showhere").innerHTML +=
                        "<img src=" + data[0].imageUrl + " height="+50+" width="+50+">";
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Result:

[image]